# Are there references in Rick and Morty S07E07 "Wet Kuat Amortican Summer" connected to "Wet Hot American Summer" besides the title?

Tags: rick-and-morty

The title of *Rick and Morty*’s season 7 episode 7, *Wet Kuat Amortican Summer*, is a clear homage to the 2001 comedy film *[Wet Hot American Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_Hot_American_Summer)*. But does the episode have any other connections to the movie, besides the name? Are there any plot elements or jokes that are inspired by or reference the film?

I've looked at the [Rick and Morty wiki article for the episode](https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Wet_Kuat_Amortican_Summer), but I can only find references to *Total Recall*, *Adventure Time*, and *Squid Game*.

Answer (score 2):

As with many other episode titles, the title is mostly a ridiculous pun on a film title based on some specifics of this episode.
I couldn't find any official sources, so this is guesswork.

- Since the episode is centred around Morty and Summer, this is reflected in the title: Morty and Summer → Mortican Summer (and, in a way, Morty "*can* indeed Summer", because they have a telepathic link and are initially (spinally) bound together).
  This kind of "pun" is very common in episode titles (*Edge of Tomorty: Rick Die Rickpeat*, *Never Ricking Morty*, *Childrick of Mort*, *Mort Dinner Rick Andre*, *A Rickconvenient Mort*, &c.).
- The way Morty and Summer end up merged together is referred to as a 'kuato', based on the character from [Total Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_(1990_film)#Plot) (see also [this image](https://static1.cbrimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Total-Recall-feature-George-Kuato.jpg)). Hence the titular "kuat" (that variation of the word is also used regularly in the episode).
- This merging is caused by the reaction of the Attribute Slider with the water in the swimming pool at Jimmy's place. Hence the "wet" (no Gremlins references, though).
- Summer camps and the "frolf" mixer at Jimmy's house share a few characteristics: teenagers coming together for physical activities, potential hookups, and, especially, popularity contests.
  The last one is important because it's the reason Summer and Morty end up in the pool in the first place.
- And a less convincing, probably just coincidental connection: in the 2001 film [Wet Hot American Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_Hot_American_Summer), the camp's director is called Beth, who "*struggles to keep her counselors in order—and her campers alive*". In the episode, Beth's concern is the reason Rick goes looking for his grandchildren.